# Excel VBA hangs when expanding [+] workbooks object variable in locals window

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I'm having a problem trying to debug some code I've written that opens a shared Excel file from SharePoint (in desktop Excel app), scrapes schedule data, makes a few changes, saves and closes that file, then populates the scraped data into the current workbook formatted as a calendar.

As is typical, the code executes fine for me, but only works about 50% of the time when another user runs it.  I'm still searching for fixes to those bugs - they are not the reason for my question today.  I'll try as best I can to describe my problem and hopefully someone can tell what I'm doing wrong.

First step I do is to check whether the SharePoint file exists and if so, open it (no problems/errors typically encountered here for myself or anyone else):

```
Sub getcalendardata()

...define variables...

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

schedule = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Schedule/Shared Documents/Schedule.xlsx"
    
If URLExists(schedule) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Schedule not found.  Check internet connection, login to Office 365, and try again."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set schedulewb = Workbooks.Open(schedule, False, False)
schedulewb.AutoSaveOn = False
Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
Set schedulews = schedulewb.Worksheets("Design")

...more code here...

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

```
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    
Dim Request As Object
Dim ff As Integer
Dim rc As Variant

On Error GoTo EndNow
Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

With Request
  .Open "GET", url, False
  .Send
  rc = .StatusText
End With

Set Request = Nothing
If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

Exit Function

EndNow:
On Error Goto 0

End Function
```

*** Occasionally, I run into issues with the cached file in MS Office's Upload Center becoming out-dated and asking to save a copy or discard changes, but that is a problem for another day.

The main problem I've come here for is that after stepping through the Workbooks.Open line, if I open the "Locals Window" to view the stored variables and try and expand the Workbook object "schedulewb" (Here:
[Locals Window during code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxQWC.png)), code execution seems to stop or go into an infinite loop.  It's like VBA is trying to expand the schedulewb object to display the properties, but isn't getting a response, so it just waits.  I've not been patient enough to see if it ever self recovers.

The only thing I see is that the Locals Window schedulewb line goes blank (like it's trying to expand) and I can no longer step through, continue, or reset/end the code execution.  I can however, break/pause the execution, at which point, schedulewb returns to the Locals Window list and I'm able to expand it with a very brief delay.  Restarting or resetting code execution after this just puts the program into the previous stall pattern and the only recovery option (besides waiting potentially forever) is to close and restart excel via Task Manager.  Interestingly, the actual Schedule Workbook I'm trying to peak inside now shows up in the Office Upload Center as a pending upload or having just been synced.

I've tried bypassing SharePoint by opening a local version of the Schedule Workbook saved to my computer, and as expected, I can interact with the Locals Window variables without consequence.

Is there something wrong with setting a SharePoint Workbook to a variable like I've done?
Has an upload/refresh been triggered by me trying to inspect the object properties, causing some other uncontrollable VBA/SharePoint event to infinitely loop in the background?
Could this be connected somehow to the Upload Center cache headache that I think is unrelated?

Thank you in advance for any insight...

Comment: The locals toolwindow (and the VBA runtime) can indeed get into an infinite loop trying to resolve properties, when the objects involved have cyclical dependencies (i.e. A depends on B which depends on A). Normally in a dream world `Property Get` accessors do not have side-effects, so running them merely pulls a value and that's the end of the story. But some objects in various object model libraries do not adhere to these modern code standards, and evaluating a property can trigger side-effects. When it's code doing it nobody notices, but when it's the *locals* toolwindow, things can go wrong

Comment: The `Workbook/ThisWorkbook` data type of `schedulewb` is rather interesting, it should be just `Workbook`. How is `schedulewb` declared?

Comment: If the local workbook works fine, the problem could be with the getter for the `Path` or `FullFilename` property, which may have the side-effect of somehow validating that path (IIRC one of them throws an error if the workbook isn't saved, which is another thing property getters shouldn't be doing, but the modern best practices are lessons learned from that period in time where the Excel object model was being designed, so a lot of libraries don't follow these basic design guidelines), which means it hits the network whenever it's evaluated. Wrapping it with your own class should work.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue with MS OneDrive / Sharepoint vs local files. Curious if you ever found a solution?